# Using PHP class in parent namespace

Tags: php

I am just trying to wrap my head around this whole concept. I am attempting to put frequently/globally used class properties and methods in the uppermost namespace and use them inside of the other classes.

So I have a namespace called `App`:

Filename: core.php

```
namespace App;

class Core {

    public function version() {
      return '1.0';
    }

}
```

Filename: settings.php

```
namespace App\Core;

use Core; // I know this is wrong

class Settings {

    public function getCurrent() {
      return 'The current version is: '.$this->Core->version(); // How do I do this?
    }

}
```

Filename: index.php

```
include('core.php');
include('settings.php');

$app = new App\Core;

echo $app->version(); // 1.0 OK...
echo $app->settings->getCurrent(); // Echo: The current version is: 1.0
```

So in the example above, how would I use all the functions inside of the `Core` class throughout the app inside of other classes in other namespaces?

Comment: Create object of class `Core` in a `Settings`

Comment: This is really a bad idea to create instance of other object in a class, and then use methods of a class in this instance. You should rethink you classes or explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: Create an object of class `Core` and **pass** it to `Settings` when you create an object of `Settings`. Either as an constructor argument or by calling a setter method. Yes this seems tedious, but ultimately you'll run better with this. In the long run, use a [`Dependency Injection Container`](http://fabien.potencier.org/do-you-need-a-dependency-injection-container.html).

Comment: @u_mulder Why is something that's seemingly so simple becoming so complicated to achieve? What is the easiest way to use global/frequent functions inside all your classes?

Comment: @JROB Whether you want to follow a dependency injection pattern or not, your code simply fails because you never actually made an object of `App\Core` available to `App\Core\Settings`. So the answer to *"How do I do this?"* is: Have an object of `App\Core` available at the place you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot test right now but I would do somethingh like this:

Core.php

```
namespace App;

class Core {

    public static function version() {
      return '1.0';
    }

}
```

then Settings.php

```
    require('Core.php');

    class Settings {

        public function getCurrent() {
          return 'The current version is: '.Core::version(); 
        }

    }
```

and finally:

```
include('Core.php');
include('Settings.php');

$app = new Settings;

echo Core::version() // 1.0 OK...
echo $app->settings->getCurrent(); // Echo: The current version is: 1.0
```